# Does MAX3421 need USB drivers?

Tags: usb, nrf52, usb-hostcontroller

I am using a NRF52840 and I want to configure it as USB host. For this I am using MAX3421 IC. Now I have implemented the code and it gives me timeout error. For MAX3421 to work does it need some USB class driver initialization??

Currently I haven't included any USB drivers. I am communicating with the peripheral USB device using SPI protocol only. I am able to detect the Peripheral USB but not able to enumerate it. It gives me timeout error. What am I missing here? Do I also need a USB stack?

Comment: Which SDK do you use? If you use the nRF Connect SDK, maybe have a look at how the MAX3421E Shield is implemented in zephyr:
https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/zephyr/boards/shields/max3421e/doc/index.html